# Convert a web project to EJB Project with CDI and JPA

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

How to Convert a web project to EJB Project with CDI and JPA
Thank you.

Comment: The first part of adding JPA , CDI is done already. I just want to know how to organize, as stated in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Now using Maven archetype to generate a multi module project.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing JPA, EJB and CDI is no problem. Make sure to check that you have the right Maven dependency either `javaee-web-api` or even `javaee-api`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then you have to add the configuration files for CDI (beans.xml) and JPA (persistence.xml). All common IDEs support you to create them properly.

As for "splitting into layers" I would not recommend you to introduce [separate JAR files](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/packaging002.htm) or even create an EAR if it is not absolutely necessary. It would be necessary if the same beans or business logic will be used by several projects. If you separate into different projects especially by using libraries, the time round-trip time will increase significantly. Instead of waiting 15 seconds for an automatic redeploy you will need to rebuild your packages using maven and redeploy (> 40 sec) if you change code in libraries.

You can organize your layers using packages if you want to do so, but in practice your naming conventions and the annotations @Entity, @Stateless, @WebServlet should already identify your different layers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.    " It would be necessary if the same beans or business logic will be used by several projects". Yes .. this is what we want to achieve finally.

Comment: Ok then it makes sense. Here is an older post to get you started by using a WAR, it includes a small example: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_ee_6_ejb_31 
Netbeans has a nice default EAR template for maven that you can use as reference